# JDBC and Sql Server 2008 Connectivity

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2

I am accessing an SQL server 2008 Database through JDBC4.0. the problem is I can access my DB just when my glassfish server is restarted, it run the code normally but once, if i make any changes into the code i have to restart the glassfish server otherwise it generate the following error.

> WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : Native Library C:\Windows\System32\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader

Kindly guide me what should i do to solve this problem i am using Eclipse editor. and my code is

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=ProductDB; integratedSecurity=true;";
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connected");
```

Comment: this is a WARNING not an error.

Comment: yes but i cant access the db table and other data

Comment: then you need to update your question because you stated " I can access my DB" in the question.

Comment: yes i can access my db only one time, if i make changes into the java files, i have to restart my glassfish server, otherwise this warning or error is generated

Answer (score 1):

If you have a data source correctly defined in GlassFish you should be able to simply re-deploy your application in order to see changes to .java files (you can even use hot deploy although my experience with that has been less than great). XML files shouldn't even need a redeploy.

Update: I see from your edit you are loading the driver etc manually. I suggest you let GlassFish manage the data source and use resource injection to acquire a connection.

Edit: Re-reading your question properly... you don't need the `sqljdbc_quth.dll` library if you are using sql authentication but it will speeds up authentication with the sql server. I tried it out with one of our products but it didn't make any noticeable difference so I've not bothered since.

Comment: but if i dont use this dll, my db data is not loaded

Comment: You do need `sqljdbc_auth.dll` if you use the windows integrated security to authenticate

Answer (score 0):

If you do any changes in xml or .java file definitely you have to restart.

If you use re loadable resource-bundle to read properties file its ok.

**Updated :**
Just go to Project in top bar than check "Build Automatically". It will stop auto building the project and saves your precious time.

Comment: thanx suleo, everytime i make changes i have to restart glassfish... is there any better solution, coz this is too hectic

Comment: Please tell me ,are you using any IDE for Development ?